# Unable to install Pandas for Python in RHEL 8

Tags: python, pandas, rhel

I am trying to install pandas for Python in my RHEL 8 server. I tried listing pandas packages using `yum list pandas` and it gave me the below package python3-pandas.x86_64 under available packages.

But, when I try to install this package using `yum install python3-pandas.x86_64`, it shows the below error:

> **Problem: package python3-pandas-0.25.3-1.el8.x86_64 requires python3-matplotlib, but none of the providers can be installed
>
> conflicting requests
>
> nothing provides libqhull.so.7()(64bit) needed by python3-matplotlib-3.0.3-3.el8.x86_64 (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)**

Do I need to install libqhull.so.7()(64bit) explicitly? If so, can you please let me know how I can do that? I don't see any relevant packages for this. Also, as per the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/pdf/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-8-Considerations_in_adopting_RHEL_8-en-US.pdf), it says `libqhull` is already available as part RHEL 8. But I don't see the package. Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many packages, including `libqhull`, live in the [CodeReady Linux Builder](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/15/introducing-codeready-linux-builder/) repo.

To enable it in RHEL 8, run:

```
ARCH=$( /bin/arch )
subscription-manager repos --enable "codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-${ARCH}-rpms"
```